# Fedora 8 howto rebuild custom PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, fedora, rebuild

I am running a wiki server for my group at work and recently moved it to a Fedora 8 OS.  Everything works great except that an extension I wrote that contacts an MsSql server fails because the function mssql_connect is not there.

On my old server I used "Free TDS" (with ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freetds --enable-msdblib) and built PHP with:
./configure \
--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs \
--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql \
**--with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds** \
--enable-safe-mode \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-inline-optimization \
--enable-magic-quotes --enable-xml \
--with-gd \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr/lib \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib

Is there a way I can easily rebuild PHP with the "--with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds" configuration on Fedora?  I would like to use yum to do this, but I don't see how.  More to the point, I would like to avoid having to build everything from scratch.  It's not that I don't know how, I would just like to avoid it.

Thanks for your your advice,
~Eric

Comment: a tangential comment - given that Fedora is a relatively fast-moving Linux distro that doesn't (AFAIK) really get involved with long-term support of releases, is it a good idea to just now move over to FC8 when FC10 is the current release>

Comment: I am locked down by our IT department or I would. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer to adding mssql is as easy as "yum install php-mssql".  Fixed my problem without any messing around.  FreeTDS is installed an easily configurable.  Thanks everyone who tried to answer or left a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Please post output from your build. Is it failing because /usr/local/freetds is missing?

If it is, can you use yum to install it, or download and compile [freetds](http://www.freetds.org/) yourself. I haven't done this but it'll be something like this...

1. Open shell and navigate to directory with freetds archive.
2. Execute tar zxvf  to extract.
3. Execute cd
4. Run ./configure for the freetds build
5. Run make, (sudo) make install

Then find where freetds is installed and pass that folder to the ./configure command for PHP.

Comment: I was hoping to not do this and tell yum how to find freetds when installing PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Get [SQL Server Driver for PHP](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/PHP-Driver.aspx), I don't think that you have to rebuild php to use this driver. I suggest you to use vendor's driver.